# What exactly is @implementation NSArray (Find) and the Warning it gives?

Tags: iphone, nsarray, implementation

A couple of questions regarding the following code:

```
@implementation NSArray (Find)
- (NSArray *)findAllWhereKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath equals:(id)value {
   NSMutableArray *matches = [NSMutableArray array];
   for (id object in self) {
     id objectValue = [object valueForKeyPath:keyPath];
     if ([objectValue isEqual:value] || objectValue == value) [matches addObject:object];         
   }
   return matches;
}
```

1- What does (Find) do? I've seen other words like this when doing these implementations, so what exactly is it doing? Is it a keyword, or just for me to know?

2- I got the code from here: http://probablyinteractive.com/2009/2/13/keypaths.html But when I place it on my project and call it

```
NSArray *filterResults = [allResults findAllWhereKeyPath:@"firstname" equals:firstname];
```

it returns the warning *'NSArray' may not respond to '-findAllWhereKeyPath:equals:'* and if I run it, it crashes.
I've placed the code at the beginning of the .m, at the .h and changed it to NSMutableArray, but I keep getting the warning. So, how should I solve this?

Comment: "Find" is a category that you've added to NSArray. So where and in which .m and .h files did you add this? And what do you mean you changed it to NSMutableArray?

Comment: That last sentence was just stating all the trial and errors I've done to try and make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This method returns all keyPaths, that contains value object.
2. To make this category work you should do the following:
   Create NSArray(Find).h and NSArray(Find).m files:

NSArray(Find).h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSArray(Find)
- (NSArray *)findAllWhereKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath equals:(id)value;
@end
```

NSArray(Find).m:

```
@implementation NSArray (Find)
- (NSArray *)findAllWhereKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath equals:(id)value {
   NSMutableArray *matches = [NSMutableArray array];
   for (id object in self) {
     id objectValue = [object valueForKeyPath:keyPath];
     if ([objectValue isEqual:value] || objectValue == value) [matches addObject:object];         
   }
   return matches;
}
```

Both files should be added to your project. Import NSArray(Find).h to the .m file, where you want to use your category:

```
#import "NSArray(Find).h"
```

`findAllWhereKeyPath:equals:` should work then.

Comment: First question was for the meaning of (Foo). Your answer gave me a warning since it's returning an NSMutableArray and it wants an NSArray.

Comment: @elcool you definitely should read about categories in objective-c: http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html. Re NSMutableArray problem - Please post a warning. I don't see any problems here, but if you really want to return non-mutable object you may replace return statement with "return [NSArray arrayWithArray:matches];"

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. I created the .h and .m files and played around with NSMutableArray and NSArray.  And yes, I'll read about categories, thanks